# Is there is any xml to json parser that can be used in oracle query?

Tags: xml, oracle

select xmlParserJson(column1) from table;
and that will give xml data converted to json.

If offical oracle xml to json parse that will be recomended .

If not offical can you tell me the method to install and run xml parse .
Thanks

Comment: An XML fragment cannot be unambiguously represented by JSON, so the thing you are asking for cannot exist.

Comment: When we work on any language we are able to convert xml to json . so why not in oracle . May be some third party .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can you tell me the method to install and run xml parse

```
SELECT XMLTYPE( your_xml_string )
FROM   DUAL
```

Will parse your XML.

If you want to extract the values then you can use [`XMLTABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions269.htm#CIHGGHFB) or [`XMLQUERY`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions265.htm#SQLRF06209) to get the values out of the XML.

> will give xml data converted to json.

Parse the XML and extract the values using the above methods and then use the Oracle 12.2 functions [`JSON_ARRAY`, `JSON_OBJECT`, `JSON_ARRAYAGG` and `JSON_OBJECTAGG`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ADJSN/generation.htm#ADJSN-GUID-6C3441E8-4F02-4E95-969C-BBCA6BDBBD9A) to create the JSON from the data.

> How can i parse `<xml><name>himanshu</name></xml>` to be covert to json in oracle by these methods.

First, you can read the documentation and the examples in it and try it yourself. But you could try:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECTAGG( id VALUE text )
FROM   XMLTABLE(
         '/xml/*'
         PASSING XMLTYPE( '<xml><name>himanshu</name></xml>')
         COLUMNS id   VARCHAR2(200) PATH './name()',
                 text VARCHAR2(200) PATH './text()'
       );
```

I'm not on an Oracle 12c system at the moment so it is untested.

Comment: How can i parse <xml><name>himanshu</name></xml> to be covert to json in oracle by these methods. @ MT0 . I have a xmlType field which have xml data and need to convert that to json . how can i do in oracle  query in select statement ?

Comment: see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44672324/i-have-running-json-object-in-oracle-12-1-0-2-and-it-is-saying-error-why