# I have running json_object in oracle 12.1.0.2 and it is saying error . why?

Tags: json, oracle

I have run this query .I am new to oracle.

```
> CREATE TABLE sample_emp (   empno     NUMBER(4)    NOT NULL PRIMARY
> KEY,   ename     VARCHAR2(10),   hiredate  DATE,   sal      
> NUMBER(7,2) ); 
>  INSERT INTO sample_emp VALUES (7369, 'Smith',
> '17-DEC-1980',  800);
>  INSERT INTO sample_emp VALUES (7782, 'Clark',
> '09-JUN-1981', 2450);
>  INSERT INTO sample_emp VALUES (7839, 'King', 
> '17-NOV-1981', 5000); COMMIT;
> 
> SELECT * from sample_emp SELECT json_object ('ename' VALUE
> d.ename,'hiredate' VALUE d.hiredate) FROM sample_emp d
```

oracle version

[image]

error coming [image]

Can we check that particular keyword exist in oracle so that i can check about

> json_object

is present in oracle . and why this error is coming?

Comment: `JSON_OBJECT` (and various other JSON functions) appears to have been [added in Oracle 12.2.0.1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ADJSN/changes.htm#ADXDB6162).

Comment: So can you give me the other method to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

Working fine for "Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production". You can try using concat operator.

```
 SELECT '{"ename":"'||d.ename||'","hiredate":"'||d.hiredate||'"}' from sample_emp d;
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON_OBJECT is available from DB 12.2 onwards

Comment: This answer doesn't fully explain why the error is occuring

Comment: You will need to upgrade your Database to 12.2 to get JSON_OBJECT utility, it is not available in version 12.1.0.2